# Kundera cassandra - Transaction rollback and Entity update

Tags: java, cassandra, kundera

I use Kundera-Cassandra 3.2 and want to use the transaction management from Kundera.

My handling looks like this:

```
EntityManager manager = repo.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager(CassandraRepository.getProperties());

try{
    manager.getTransaction().begin();

    this.repo.update(account1, manager); //calls the merge method of the Entitymanager
    this.repo.save(account2, manager); //calls the persist method of the Entitymanager

    manager.getTransaction().commit();

} catch(Exception e){
    if(manager.getTransaction().isActive()){
        manager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
} finally {
    manager.clear();
    manager.close();
}
```

When an error in the `this.repo.save(account2, manager);` occurs, the manager rollbacks the transaction, but does not do a update statement, he makes a delete statement for the merge method. The reason for this is, when calling the merge methode, kundera creates an insert statement and not an update. But how to say Kundera to make an update to rollback the transaction also with an update.

Logs:

```
12:42:41.185 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase - Returning delete query DELETE FROM "account" WHERE "id" = 'MCSP-000000000004'.
12:42:41.211 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase - Returning delete query DELETE FROM "account" WHERE "id" = 'MCSP-000000000005'.
```

EDIT (my repository):

```
public class CassandraRepository<T> {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public static Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        properties.put(CassandraConstants.CQL_VERSION, CassandraConstants.CQL_VERSION_3_0);
        return properties;
    }



    public void update(T entity, EntityManager manager) throws Exception{
        try {
            manager.merge(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void save(T entity, EntityManager manager) throws Exception{
        try {
            manager.persist(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you are invoking inside save and update methods ?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: This seems to be a bug.. please raise an issue on [Kundera Git](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues), we are looking into it.

Comment: @karthikmanchala issue has been created https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/829

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JPA, to update an entity you have to first bring it into managed state (by fetching it)

Example:-

```
        PersonCassandra p = entityManager.find(PersonCassandra.class, "2");

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        p.setMonth(Month.JAN);
        entityManager.merge(p);
        entityManager.persist(p3);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Issue is not with INSERT and UPDATE statements since both are similar for Cassandra, under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will change it to `merge` and `persist`. But this will not solve the problem.

Comment: @K.E. I dont mean to change to `merge` and `persist`.. You need to fetch the entity before updating..

Comment: Perfect! That was my fault - I fetched the entity with another instance of the `EntityManager`. When I fetch the entity with the same manager instance the rollback works like a charm. Thank you